# ExtJS CRUD operations on Grid Panel and Grails backend

Tags: extjs

I am an absolute novice and have been working and struggling with ExtJS ! I am supposed to get a list of user records and dipslay them on Ext grid Panel. I have an ExtJS frontend and Grails ( Groovy Controllers ) backend. I have referred to a few links like:

```
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/example/grid/row-editing.html
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/example/restful/restful.html
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/example/writer/writer.html

The api property ( or ) tag ( or )attribute ( I don't know what it is called ) helps me in getting the list of JSON objects to be displayed in the Grid. Also, when I select a row and click on Delete, the request is reaching the delete action in my controller. But my problems begins here: how do I make sure that:

1) the selected row is deleted from Database? How do I pass the identifier or something to controller so that it will delete the record?

2) When I add a row, how do I pass the field values to backend Controller?

Most of the code is same as given in the restful link above. For reference, this is my Datastore:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1gQyLCt6xWXTm-OUgYu7hku47r5WcS0my5yPBSKj2B7I/edit?usp=sharing
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Rest proxy, ExtJS will auto generate the urls for you, based on the url stub that you specify. So if your proxy is configured to point to something like: /api/users, the following urls would be generated for each of the 4 actions:

- read: /api/users (GET)
- create: /api/users (POST)
- update: /api/users/SomeIDFromTheUpdatedRecord (PUT)
- delete: /api/users/SomeIDFromTheDeletedRecord (DELETE)

As you can see, the end point for each request is precisely the same (api/users), but for PUT and DELETEs, the id of the affected record is included in the URL automatically.

And of course, with POST and PUT requests, you can add any additional params that you'd like to send through to the server, although this will be done automatically when you persist the model instance via the store's configured proxy.

Comment: Thank you buddy ... Yes you are a buddy now :)

Comment: But the parameter or the ID that it appends by default to the request URL is something called as _dc. I read somewhere that it can be overridden by specifying encode: true in the DataStore. That added the form data to the request. Which kind of helped me. But I have another issue now ! The REST based ExtJS GRID for CRUD operations that we find on the sencha site ... I used it and I see that when we click on 'Add' it is sending two requests. Any idea on that?

Comment: _dc is just a cache buster, it's not an ID.

Comment: RE: the create method on the restful grid, I am only seeing it create one request.

Comment: @exitdissolve ... nothing seems to work properly. I am actually emulating the example given in http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/example/restful/restful.html.

Comment: I have many questions like:

1. When I click on 'Add' in the CRUD grid panel, it is automatically sending a Save request. I didn't add any data yet.
2. You mentioned about /api/users/SomeIDFromTheDeletedRecord ... how do set the parameter/SomeID here?

Like I said, I somehow am not able control my data flow. How do I stop the 'Save/Create' request until I actually add data and click on 'Update' in the row editor. Would you mind if I email you my code and discuss more there?

Comment: RE: the auto saving, I'm not sure. What happens if you take autoSync: true off?

Comment: RE: the ID in the url, the point of the Restful store is that you don't have to add this; rather, it gets added to the URL dynamically by the framework based on the type of action being taken on the model instance in question.